# Convert reports from Reporting Server 2008 to PDF Document

Tags: c#, ssrs-2008

I’m recreating some crystal reports in SSRS 2008
We use a web service to convert Crystal reports to PDF files.
The Crystal Reports in web service is using a dll named CRAXDRT.
I want to modify the web service to convert SSRS Reports to PDF.
Any suggestions
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the report execution API that is exposed by ssrs. In particular, look at the render and render2 methods. The following link shows you more at MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.aspx